# Android Fileprovider unable to get uri

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

I use Fileprovider to get Uri of an image I saved manually in a folder "F1" in Device Storage.When I tried to get the Uri,i get NullPointerException. The Exception is at where I try to access the Uri. I have declared provider in Manifest and declared the paths in xml file.Have I set the paths wrong in xml?

Code:

```
 folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/F1");
folder.mkdirs();
 File file1=new File(folder+"/37deb43.jpg");
            Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file1);
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/share_file_paths"
                >
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
```

@xml/share_file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="F1">
</external-files-path>
</paths>
```

Exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:604)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:578)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:416)
        at com.globemaster.com.architecturecomponentstest.mvvm.java_technical_programs.JavaTechnicalActivity.fetchuri(JavaTechnicalActivity.java:179)
        at com.globemaster.com.architecturecomponentstest.mvvm.java_technical_programs.JavaTechnicalActivity.access$200(JavaTechnicalActivity.java:30)
        at com.globemaster.com.architecturecomponentstest.mvvm.java_technical_programs.JavaTechnicalActivity$4.onClick(JavaTechnicalActivity.java:130)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: whats new File(file+"/37deb43.jpg"); the `file` argument there? shouldn't that be `folder` ??

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I typed wrong.That was folder itself.I changed it now

Comment: also use `file1` in `getUriForFile` as seen in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.The problem was in the second argument in `getUriForFile()`.

```
Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file1);
```

I appended "provider" to `"BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID"` below.It was not needed.The below code works fine now.But thank you all for your effort in trying to help me
..

```
Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,file1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a copy-paste error in your first snippet! Try this:

```
File folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "F1");
folder.mkdirs();
File file1=new File(folder, "37deb43.jpg");
Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file1);
Log.d("URI", "Uri is: " + uri)
```

Comment: That was a mistake.i changed it.But it was  folder in my code in the class.

Comment: please post output of log

Comment: I have included above the Exception I got .The code was in a method.Only I didnt include the method here.

Comment: Could it be the path I set in share_file_paths

Answer (score 0):

my file provider path is this :

```
<paths><root-path name="sdcard1" path="." /></paths>
```

and this code is how i get uri

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
     getApplicationContext(),
     getApplicationContext().packageName,
     File(
          Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
          it.path?.split(":")?.lastOrNull()
     )
)
```